# Rotate and Crop UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, cgimage

Imagine I have an UIImage.
I need to rotate and then crop it in the global coordinate system (not UIImage coordinate system). So the resulted image will be cropped **and** rotated.

How can I do this? CGImageCreateWithImageInRect will crop image only in the image-relative coordinates.

[image]

PS Answer in comments. You should use CIImage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help

```
//init
CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageRef];
//rotation
CIImage *rotatedImage = [image imageByApplyingTransform:someTransform];
//crop
CIImage *croppedImage = [rotatedImage imageByCroppingToRect:someRect];
```

Comment: I just tested it and it's worked! I should note that Affine rotation rotates image around it lower left corner (zero point of the CIImage coordinate system) and not around its center so you should be careful with the coordinates when applying the crop.

Comment: Can you post code how you make calculation for someRect? I rotate image but I can't figure out how to crop rect I want because after rotation it is not in same place as before.

Comment: Not working for me. "imageByCroppingToRect" give me empty image after applying "CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees);"

Answer (score 0):

For rotation, you need to apply

```
 CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.imageView.transform,deltaX,deltaY);
 transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, recognizer.rotation);
 transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -deltaX, -deltaY);
 self.imageView.transform = transform;
```

For cropping, simply change the frame of your imageView

To convert local coordinates'image, simply use :

```
// converts a point in local coordinate space to window coordinates. 
[self.imageView convertPoint:localPosition toView:nil];

// use this method to calculate a view's origin in window space like this:
[self.imageView convertPoint:self.imageView.frame.origin toView:nil];
```

If you plan to integrate an image editor to your app, you may wish to consider using a third party like : https://github.com/heitorfr/ios-image-editor

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to get transformations for the internal use, not for the UIView.