# Not in center rotate and crop image ios

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, cgcontext, ciimage

I want to crop this image

[image: Crop this image]

And get this result

[image: And get this result]

I have been banging my head around for some time now and still can't achieve this.

Should I do this with CIImage or CGContext?

How to calculate cutting frame after rotating image?

Comment: Do you have any current code or do you just not know where to start?

Comment: I made too much attempts that failed, many calculations and transformation and I'm so confused right now that it is better to say that I don't have any code.

Comment: If you can read Objective-C, [here's something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822730/rotate-and-crop-uiimage).

Comment: I can read Objective-C and I saw this answer but I don't know how to calculate rect ("someRect" in link you provided) which I have to crop because when I rotate image image size change and also rect I want to crop has different coordinates.

Comment: Do you know the rect of the image you want to crop, or do you want to be able to calculate where the insect is?

Comment: I know the rect of the image I want to crop before I make rotation, when I rotate image rect I want to crop will have different origin and I don't know how to calculate that new origin.

Comment: Do you know how much you want to rotate (the transformation)?

Comment: Yes, I know that too

Comment: @NFilip: How did you've solved? looking for center (vertically) & right (horizontal) crop.